# Selenium webdriver to access E-CAC using certificate A1

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, ssl, webdriver, certificate

I'm trying hardly to find a way to select the certificate on a web page, using python. I've tried the exemples but still not working. Does anyone can help me?

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

navegador = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe")
navegador.get("https://cav.receita.fazenda.gov.br/ecac/")

navegador.find_element_by_id("login-dados-certificado").click()
navegador.find_element_by_id("cert-digital").click()
```

Comment: Please add your code to the code bracket

Comment: What error are you facing? Put the errors in the post.

Comment: It isn’t an error, I just can’t select the certificate

Answer (score 1):

If you want try using Registry Editor and use ChromeDriver try:

1-) Press Windwos + R and type it "regedit".

2-) Rigth Click in "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies", select new -> Key and put the name "Google", then into this key add key "Chrome" and into this one add outher key called "AutoSelectCertificateForUrls". The full path need to be this "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls".

3-) Rigth click on AutoSelectCertificateForUrls, new -> String Value, and put the name "1".

4-) Rigth click on "1", modified then copy and paste this JSON "{"pattern":"https://urlFromTheSiteYouWantAccess","filter":{"ISSUER":{"CN":"your cn"},"SUBJECT":{"CN":"your certificate cn"}}}".

If you just want to access the E-CAC with one certificate you can manually edit the Json above with the url that the button send the certificate and the Issuer and Subject information of the certificate you want that the chrome choose for you.

But if want use mutiples certificates you can use this code of python to open a certificate, get the informations about the issuer and subject and change the Json in StringValue "1" in registry AutoSelectCertificateForUrls .

The imports.

```py
from os import times
import winreg
from OpenSSL import crypto
from selenium import webdriver
```

**The method to Open a certificate:**

```py
def GetCertificate(pathOfCertificate, passwordOfCertifcate):
    pkcs12 = crypto.load_pkcs12(open(pathOfCertificate, 'rb').read(), passwordOfCertifcate)   
    return pkcs12.get_certificate()
```

**The method to update the Json in StringValue in regitry key "AutoSelectCertificateForUrls":**

```py
def UpdateStringValue(strigValueName,newValueOfStrinValue, stringValuePath):
  key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, stringValuePath, 0, winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
  winreg.SetValueEx(key, strigValueName, 0, winreg.REG_SZ, newValueOfStrinValue)
  winreg.CloseKey(key)
```

**The main where I declaring 2 varibles for path where is the string value and the name of string value. In my case is "1":**

```py
pathOfstringValue = 'SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls'
stringValueName = '1'
```

**Get the certificate and the informations of Issuer and Subject:**

```py
certificate = GetCertificate("C:\yourCrtificatePath\\Certificate.pfx", 'certificatePassword')
subject = certificate.get_subject()
issuer = certificate.get_issuer()
```

**The Urls the firth is where the certificate will be send and the other is the page where we have the button to login with certicate:**

```py
url_where_certificate_will_be_send = "https://notacarioca.rio.gov.br/"
url = 'https://notacarioca.rio.gov.br/senhaweb/login.aspx'
```

**Building the json, (sorry for the ugly way to handling with the string) and calling the method to edit the string value registry:**

```py
json = '{"pattern":"' + url_where_certificate_will_be_send + '","filter":{"ISSUER":{"CN":"' + issuer.CN + '","C":"' + issuer.C + '","O":"' + issuer.O + '"},"SUBJECT":{"CN":"' + subject.CN + '","C":"' + subject.C + '","O":"' + subject.O + '"}}}'
UpdateStringValue(stringValueName, json, pathOfstringValue)
```

**And finally the code to click the button for login with certificate:**

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(url)

btn_certificate_login = driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_cphCabMenu_imgLoginICP')
btn_certificate_login.click()
times.sleep(2.4)
driver.quit()
```

For download the code visit my github [here](https://github.com/JimmyelsonSilvaPeres/PythonLoginWithCertificateSelenium/tree/main)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30291806)

Comment: Oh sorry for that, i am new in answer questions in stack. I will edit my answer! thanks for the tip.